A question on AOPS from AMC 12 left without a solution.
So I was doing some math questions on AOPS when i stumbled across this question which did not have a solution for it. I really want to know the solution to this problem so please help me.
2002 AMC 12P Problem 22:-
Under the new AMC 10, 12 scoring method, 6 points are given for each correct answer, 2.5 points are given for each unanswered question, and no points are given for an incorrect answer. Some of the possible scores between 0 and 150 can be obtained in only one way, for example, a score of 104.5 can be obtained with 17 correct answers, 1 unanswered question, and 7 incorrect answers, and also with 12 correct answers and 13 unanswered questions. There are scores that can be obtained in exactly three ways. What is their sum?
a) 175
b) 179.5
c) 182
d) 188.5
e) 201
I have no idea how to solve this, I recently started learning number theory and algebra but am not able to solve this question.
By the way the answer given was:- d) 188.5

When you say AMC do you mean the American or Australian competition? They both (annoyingly) have the same acronym. Based on the earlier linked comment to the American paper not matching your question, I am guessing it is the Australian paper, but please clarify... it may be neither.

@RedFive The P in AMC 12P apparently refers to "practice". See https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/AMC/a-activities/a7-problems/practice1012p/pdf1012p/AMC12Pprob.pdf

Yes, this question is from this paper, thanks.

Let $x, y$ be the number of correctly answered and unanswered questions respectively. Then $x+y \leq 25$ and if the score is k then $6x+2.5y=k$. Note that the "lcm" of 6 and 2.5 is $30=5*6=12*2.5$. In other words the set of ways to get some score k will be all pairs of the form $(x+5a, y-12a)$ for some $x, y$. Since $x, y \leq 25$, that means that any score that has 3 ways to obtain must have a way with $y \geq 24$ (and any score generated by pair with $y \geq 24$ must have exactly 3 ways to obtain). That gives us 3 pairs: $(0, 24), (1, 24), (0, 25)$. Computing the score of each pair and summing gives us $188.5$, which is the answer.
